# What is wrong with with my jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: xml, jquery

I am trying to make an jQuery $ajax GET request to an ASPX-page returning an XML document but is not able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loading").show();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.url.com/reports/xml.aspx",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("Year").each(function() {
    $("body").append( $(this).find("RevenueYear").text() + '<br />' });
}});​
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

​**XML**

```
<root>
   <Year>
      <RevenueYear>2011</RevenueYear>
      <RevenueType>actual</RevenueType>
   </Year>
   <Year>
      <RevenueYear>2012</RevenueYear>
      <RevenueType>estimate</RevenueType>
   </Year>
</root>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, could you please post it?

Comment: is www.url.com the same server as this script runs from?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/: `Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair That is the reason I could not get it to work.

Comment: @klick.klonk there's a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333885/how-to-parse-html-content-using-javascript-or-jquery) which has a solution in it (php-web-proxy to avoid the same-origin-policy)

Comment: @klick.klonk created an answer, so you can tick it as a solution if it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to [BNL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168056/bnl), who asked the crucial question!

According to the jQuery-documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

[Same-Origin-policy in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Some time ago, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333885/how-to-parse-html-content-using-javascript-or-jquery) here on SO - the solution is pretty simple:
Just create a web-proxy (PHP, ASP.NET, ...) to transfer the content @ server-side, so you avoid the same-origin-policy.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parseXml` function has a few syntax errors.  You have the wrong number of `}` and `)`.

It should be:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("Year").each(function() {
        $("body").append( $(this).find("RevenueYear").text() + '<br />');
    });
}
```